# StringBuider and Builder design pattern: what relation

Tags: c#, .net, string, oop, uml

Maybe my question will be silly: I have read about design pattern implementation in C# code , especially [Builder design pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/builder-design-pattern).

I wonder if [String Builder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class is an implementation of this design pattern.

Comment: same as "car" and "carpet".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really.

Consider that pattern's definition:

> Separate the construction of a complex object from its representation so that the same construction process can create different representations.

`StringBuilder` always builds a string, there is no ability to create anything else.

The purpose of `StringBuilder` is to be *mutable* when many operations are needed to create a single string, rather than creating lots intermediate string objects (and thus load the GC).

Answer (score 3):

No see: http://www.dofactory.com/net/builder-design-pattern

The builder pattern is for:

> "Separate the construction of a complex object from its representation
>   so that the same construction process can create different
>   representations."

So in the example in the link we have a car and a scooter, but we want the director to have a common interface to build both even though their construction will be different.

A dead give away is the fact that StringBuilder does not implement or inherent from anything but ISerializable. Nothing that would give it a way to implement a generic builder interface.

Although the builder pattern shares part of its name, it is unrelated. The StringBuilder is an efficient way to build strings without causing many string copies like you would do with "string1"+"string2" since strings are immutable.

To quote MSDN:

> A StringBuilder object maintains a buffer to accommodate expansions to
>   the string. New data is appended to the buffer if room is available;
>   otherwise, a new, larger buffer is allocated, data from the original
>   buffer is copied to the new buffer, and the new data is then appended
>   to the new buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Not really. StringBuilder is incredibly useful as it does not create several immutable strings before concatenating them, which can lead to wasteful memory as there are new String objects created on the Heap. Instead it uses char[] and appends them when you call StrinBuilderObj.Append(...), and then returns the string when it is finally requested in StringBuilderObj.ToString()

The Builder design pattern shows you how to build a complex object by using several smaller objects, while the implementation of StrinBuilder class has mainly to deal with not creating String objects during concatenation so as to reduce memory pressure on the Garbage collector.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

String Builder does not implement the Builder design pattern.

In the [Builder design pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/builder-design-pattern) that you linked to, each concrete builder implementation supports an interface defined by the base class that they all inherit from (abstract class Builder).

Looking at the linked documentation for [String Builder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you can see that it only implements the interface [ISerializable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The ISerializable interface does not contain any methods that support the "Building" part of the StringBuilder.

**However, the real question you should ask yourself is why you would need to build other built-in types like you build a string via StringBuilder.**
In a strongly typed language like C#, creating a bunch of Builders to build other built-in types would result in a rather unhelpful interface. Using that interface in actual development would result in a lot of casting back and forth and no real-world application.

The thing to remember with design patterns is that they help developers quickly understand the solution to the problem, but they are not applicable in every situation. Most of the time, when dealing with basic, built-in types like strings and integers, the framework provides more than enough help to get things done in a way that other developers will understand your solution.